# Assigning to List to another List previous list automatically changes

Tags: c#

I have two lists. When I assign `List1` to `List2` and I update `List1`, `List2` automatically updates too. `List2` shouldn't update. Why does this happen?

Here is my code:

```
public List<TrialBalance> TBal { get; set; }
public List<TrialBalance> PrevTBal { get; private set; }

if (this.PrevTBal == null)
{
    this.PrevTBal = this.TBal;
}

for (int x = 0; x < this.TBal.Count; x++)
{
    this.TBal[x].Balance = this.TBal[x].Balance + adjustments;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are only assigning the references, not creating a copy of either the list or the items in the list.

You should create a new list and add all the items to it.

```
 this.PrevTBal = new List<TrialBalance>(this.TBal.Select(b => clone(b));
```

Comment: there is not clone()?

Comment: @SHINHAN `clone` is what you need to do to make a copy of a `TrialBalance`.

Comment: Im confused how do I clone my TrialBalance?

Comment: @SHINHAN just create a new instance of it and assign the values.

Answer (score 3):

When you assign a `List<T>`, you're copying the handle to the actual list in memory, which means the same list instance is being referenced by both variables.

In order to avoid this, you'd need to clone the list itself.  In this case, that likely means needing to do two things - first, make a way to clone `TrialBalance`, then clone the list too:

```
// This assumes a TrialBalance.Clone() method which returns a new TrialBalance copy
this.PrevTBal = this.TBal.Select(tb => tb.Clone()).ToList();
```

Comment: This is a really popular interview question, please look into the difference between storing data on the stack or the heap.  Once you understand this point you will not have these kind of issues again http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/rmcochran/csharp_memory01122006130034PM/csharp_memory.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
if (this.PrevTBal == null)
    {
        this.PrevTBal = this.TBal;
    }
```

by:

```
if (this.PrevTBal == null)
        {
            this.PrevTBal = this.TBal.ToList();
        }
```

This way you're actually creating a copy of it instead of just refering it.